# How to find column names in pandas dataframe that contain all unique values except NaN?

Tags: pandas, unique

I want to find columns that contain all non-duplicates from a pandas data frame except NaN.

```
   x   y   z
a  1   2   A
b  2   2   B
c  NaN 3   D
d  4   NaN NaN
e  NaN NaN NaN
```

The columns "x" and "z" have non-duplicate values except NaN, so I want to pick them out and create a new data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `nunique`

```
m=df.nunique()==df.notnull().sum()
subdf=df.loc[:,m]
     x    z
a  1.0    A
b  2.0    B
c  NaN    D
d  4.0  NaN
e  NaN  NaN

m.index[m].tolist()
['x', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare length of unique values and length of values after applying `dropna()`.

Try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan],
                   "y":[2, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
                   "z":["A", "B", "D", np.nan, np.nan]})

for col in df.columns:
    if len(df[col].dropna()) == len(df[col].dropna().unique()):
        print(col)
```